# Chromium won't play mp4

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, redhat-enterprise-linux, chromium

I have chromium (version 79) installed on my Red Hat 7.6 system and cannot play any mp4 videos. I attached an image below of what it looks like when I run `chromium-browser <mp4 video>`. I have researched a bit and found a few solutions online that do not work. The first solution I found was to change the spec file line:

```
CHROMIUM_CORE_GN_DEFINES+=' ffmpeg_branding="Chromium" proprietary_codecs=false
```

to

```
CHROMIUM_CORE_GN_DEFINES+=' ffmpeg_branding="ChromeOS" proprietary_codecs=true'
```

But this ended up with an unresolvable error when I tried to build it.

The second solution I found was to to follow the steps here: https://snapcraft.io/install/chromium-ffmpeg/rhel to install the chromium-ffmpeg package which should contain the codecs. It didn't work but I was able to find chromium-ffmpeg-extra (version 69) floating around online and installed it but still no change when trying to view the mp4.

Any tips on other solutions or how to debug this further?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use the snap versions, use only the snaps for Chromium and FFmpeg codecs (Snap from https://snapcraft.io/chromium). For info, I personally use kubuntu. MP4 videos (with h.264 + AAC codecs) play nicely.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> By default, Chromium does not support proprietary codecs (like h.264, aac). Official info: https://www.chromium.org/audio-video

> So, on macOS, you need to compile Chromium with the proprietary codecs support yourself ; or download pre-compiled versions with the proprietary codecs support (https://chromium.woolyss.com/ - I am the admin of this website for many years).

source: https://superuser.com/a/1545667/951213

I can confirm the woolyss.com portable build worked for playing mp4s for me (windows though).