# Official source for portable embedded Chromium binaries, for kiosk use, with H264 support

Tags: google-chrome, video, chromium, codec, embedded

I am using Chromium in kiosk mode, for an embedded computer project.

We can find portable snapshots on https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/

**Are there official Chromium builds for portable use (i.e. without installer) on Windows x64, that have H264 support?**

Here https://www.chromium.org/audio-video/ it is mentioned:

> ==Video==
> H.264 [Google Chrome only]

Comment: See the answer here https://superuser.com/a/1545667/368970 with a link to a website that has compiled versions with all-codecs included

Comment: @Ramhound Ok this is probably the answer, I'll accept it. So if I need to have trusted executable, the only solution is to build it ourselves? Does Chrome provide an official portable version that we can use for an embedded project?